# can I use multiple texture with drawArraysInstancedANGLE?

Tags: webgl, webgl-extensions

I try to draw multiple icon on screen and I use drawArraysInstancedANGLE  method. 
I try to use multiple texture like this but some icons draw diffrent geometry, I can not find what draw like that.

I use one big icon map texture and fill icon vertex coord array with this func:

```
  FillIconTextCoordBuffer(data, mapW, mapH, i) {
    const ULiconW = data.x / mapW
    const ULiconH = data.y / mapH
    const LRiconW = (data.x + data.width) / mapW
    const LRiconH = (data.y + data.height) / mapH
    const { gl } = this.FGlobe

    this.IconMapTexCoordArr[i] = gl.createBuffer()
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.IconMapTexCoordArr[i])
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
      ULiconW, ULiconH,
      LRiconW, LRiconH,
      LRiconW, ULiconH,
      LRiconW, LRiconH,
      ULiconW, ULiconH,
      ULiconW, LRiconH]), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  }
```

and then my draw func like this:

```
  gl.uniform1f(P2DRotationForLayer, icon.rotDeg)
  gl.uniform2fv(P2DScaleLocForLayer, icon.__size)
  gl.uniform4fv(P2DOpacityLocForLayer, __iconColor)

  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(P2DoffsetForLayer, 1) // This makes it instanced!

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.IconMapVertCoordArr)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(P2DvertexPosForLayer)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(P2DvertexPosForLayer, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.IconCoordBuff)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(P2DoffsetForLayer)
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(P2DoffsetForLayer, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, IconMap[icon.mapIndex].texture)
  gl.disable(gl.BLEND)
  for (var j = this.StartCountArr.length; j--;) {
     this.DrawInstances(this.StartCountArr[j].start, this.StartCountArr[j].count, j)
  }

  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(P2DoffsetForLayer, 0)
```

and my DrawInstances func like this:

```
DrawInstances(start, count, j) {
    const {
      gl, ext,
      P2DtextCoordLocForLayer,
    } = this.FGlobe

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.IconMapTexCoordArr[j])
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(P2DtextCoordLocForLayer)
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(P2DtextCoordLocForLayer, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null)
    ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, start, 6, count)
  }
```

Actually some icons drawed right I see 2 different icon but there is one type more look like this:

```
|\
| \
|  \
|  /
| /
|/
```

my icons only two triangle like below, I dont set any shape like above,

```
______
|\   |
| \  |
|  \ |
|   \|
------
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The title asks about multiple textures, the details talk about triangle issues. What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: I try to draw different icon texture with drawArraysInstancedANGLE  extension but I see different geometry. I did not find what is draw like this. 
I ask is this possible  ?
in DrawInstances  function before every drawArraysInstancedANGLE I bind different texturecoord  and set start and instance count but I see different textures with different shapes

Comment: You haven't shown all the data you're passing in nor how `start` and `count` are computed.

Comment: they computed right, I check he value. evey abject have x and y. `this.IconCoordBuff` is contain x and y coordinates and `start`  and `count` is equal to object count.

Comment: my textureVertexcoord is one and it contains a box which is create from two triangles between -0.5, 0.5 and 0.5,-0.5 coordinates

Comment: if `start` is equal to object count then it's wrong. `start` is how many vertices to skip in the non-instanced attributes. Likely it should always be 0

Comment: for example I have 10 object with 2 coordinates  and I want to draw start from 3. object and draw 2 instances is that wrong  ? But I set vertices 2  so object count and vertices index is equal `gl.vertexAttribPointer(P2DoffsetForLayer, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)`

Comment: You want to draw 10 quads right? There are 6 quad positions, and 6 quad texture coords. They go from 0 to 5 so start is always 0. For instances, if you want to reference a different part of a buffer for isntance data then you'd set the offset in `gl.vertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: but I want to start 4 to 10 is this possible ? Another example I have 10 quads I bind plane icon coord for 0-2, and then I bind car icon coord for 2 2 and  blah blah blah .... Can I do this way that I wonder only this ?

Comment: Your drawing *instances*. Start is for the non-instanced data. The quad data so it has to be 0.  If you want to start drawing from instance #7 then for each instanced attribute you need to set `gl.vertexAttribPosition(locationOfInstancedAttribute, size, type, normalize, stride, size * sizeOfTypeInBytes * 7)`

Comment: thanks I will try tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample drawing multiple sprites from a sprite sheet using instanced drawing.

Note if it was me I'd use a matrix for each instance [like this example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-instanced-drawing.html) but I thought the code would be simpler using offset and scale here.

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
if (!ext) alert('need ANGLE_instanced_arrays');

const vs = `
attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 uv;
attribute vec2 offset;    // instanced
attribute vec2 scale;     // instanced
attribute vec2 uvOffset;  // instanced
attribute vec2 uvScale;   // instanced

uniform mat4 matrix;

varying vec2 v_uv;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * vec4(position * scale + offset, 0, 1);
  
  v_uv = uv * uvScale + uvOffset;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;
varying vec2 v_uv;
uniform sampler2D spriteAtlas;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(spriteAtlas, v_uv);
}
`;

const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
const uvLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'uv');
const offsetLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'offset');
const scaleLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'scale');
const uvOffsetLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'uvOffset');
const uvScaleLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'uvScale');
const matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'matrix');

// setup quad positions and uv
const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  0, 0,
  1, 0,
  0, 1,
  0, 1,
  1, 0,
  1, 1,
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const uvBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  0, 0,
  1, 0,
  0, 1,
  0, 1,
  1, 0,
  1, 1,
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


// create typed array for instanced data
const maxSprites = 1000;
const offsets = new Float32Array(maxSprites * 2);
const scales = new Float32Array(maxSprites * 2);
const uvOffsets = new Float32Array(maxSprites * 2);
const uvScales = new Float32Array(maxSprites * 2);

// create buffers fo instanced data
const offsetBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offsets.byteLength, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
const scaleBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, scaleBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, scales.byteLength, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
const uvOffsetBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvOffsetBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvOffsets.byteLength, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
const uvScaleBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvScaleBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvScales.byteLength, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

let spriteNdx = 0;
function addSprite(
    spriteAtlasWidth, spriteAtlasHeight,
    srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
    dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight) {
  const off0 = spriteNdx * 2;
  const off1 = off0 + 1;
  offsets[off0] = dstX;
  offsets[off1] = dstY;
  scales[off0] = dstWidth;
  scales[off1] = dstHeight;
  uvOffsets[off0] = srcX / spriteAtlasWidth;
  uvOffsets[off1] = srcY / spriteAtlasHeight;
  uvScales[off0] = srcWidth / spriteAtlasWidth;
  uvScales[off1] = srcHeight / spriteAtlasHeight;
  ++spriteNdx;
}

const sprites = [ 
   {msg: 'A', x: 0,  y:  0, w: 64, h: 32, bg: 'red',    fg: 'yellow'},
   {msg: 'B', x: 64, y:  0, w: 64, h: 32, bg: 'blue',   fg: 'white' },
   {msg: 'C', x: 0,  y: 32, w: 40, h: 32, bg: 'green',  fg: 'pink'  },
   {msg: 'D', x: 40, y: 32, w: 48, h: 32, bg: 'purple', fg: 'cyan'  },
   {msg: 'F', x: 88, y: 32, w: 40, h: 32, bg: 'black',  fg: 'red'   },
];

// make 5 sprites in an atlas
const spriteAtlasWidth = 128;
const spriteAtlasHeight = 64;
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = spriteAtlasWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = spriteAtlasHeight;
for (const spr of sprites) {
  ctx.fillStyle = spr.bg;
  ctx.fillRect(spr.x, spr.y, spr.w, spr.h);
  ctx.strokeStyle = spr.fg;
  ctx.strokeRect(spr.x + .5, spr.y + .5, spr.w - 1, spr.h - 1);
  ctx.fillStyle = spr.fg;
  ctx.font = 'bold 26px sans-serif';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText(spr.msg, spr.x + spr.w / 2, spr.y + spr.h / 2);
}
// show the atlas
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);

// copy the atlas to a texture
const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ctx.canvas);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


function render(time) {
   time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds

   spriteNdx = 0;
   const numSprites = 10;
   for (let i = 0; i < numSprites; ++i) {
     const sp = sprites[i % sprites.length];
     addSprite(
       spriteAtlasWidth, spriteAtlasHeight,
       sp.x, sp.y, sp.w, sp.h,
       Math.sin(time + i * 15) * gl.canvas.width / 2 + gl.canvas.width / 2,
       Math.cos(time + i * 17) * gl.canvas.height / 2 + gl.canvas.height / 2,
       sp.w, sp.h,
     );
  }
  
  // copy the latest sprite instance data
  // to their respective buffers and setup
  // the attributes.

  // NOTE: for the attributes it would be better
  // to use a vertex array
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(uvLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(uvLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetBuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, offsets);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(offsetLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(offsetLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(offsetLoc, 1);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, scaleBuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, scales);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(scaleLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(scaleLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(scaleLoc, 1);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvOffsetBuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, uvOffsets);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(uvOffsetLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(uvOffsetLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(uvOffsetLoc, 1);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvScaleBuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, uvScales);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(uvScaleLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(uvScaleLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(uvScaleLoc, 1);
  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  
  // pass in a projection matrix that 
  // converts to pixel space so the top
  // left corner is 0,0 and the bottom right corner
  // is canvas.width, canvas.height
  // 
  // if you had a 3d math library this would be something like
  // m4.ortho(0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, -1, 1);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc, false, [
     2 / gl.canvas.width, 0, 0, 0,
     0, -2 / gl.canvas.height, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 1, 0,
     -1, 1, 0, 1,
  ]);
  
  // note as there as only 1 texture and 
  // uniforms default to 0 we don't need to
  // bind the texture to setup a uniform
  // as the defaults happen to work.
  
  ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(
      gl.TRIANGLES,
      0,
      6,          // verts per instance
      spriteNdx,  // num instances
  );
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

note I'm not skipping instances but if you want to skip instances then you need to set the offset passed to `gl.vertexAttribPointer` for each instanced attribute. For example in the code above if you wanted to draw instances 7 to 29 it would be

```
 const numInstancesToSkip = 7;
 const numInstancesToDraw = 29 - 7 + 1;
 const size = 2;  // vec2
 const sizeOfFloat = 4;
 const offset = numInstancesToSkip * sizeOfFloat * size;

 gl.bindBuffer(offsetBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(offsetLoc, size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, offset);
 gl.bindBuffer(scaleBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(scaleLoc, size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, offset);
 gl.bindBuffer(uvOffsetBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(uvOffsetLoc, size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, offset);
 gl.bindBuffer(uvScaleBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(uvScaleLoc, size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, offset);
```

and to draw would be

```
 ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6, mumInstancesToDraw);
```

note that `offset` above is the same for each attribute because all the atrributes are the same size (2) and the same type (gl.FLOAT) and they are all in separate buffers so their base offsets are all 0. If they were different sizes or different types or mixed into the same buffer they'd all require different math.